# Compare the variances of multiple categorical distributions in a repeated measure design

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, categorical-data

I ran three model-building procedures with different parameters on the same sample and obtained the selection of my optimized hyperparameter for each outer fold (each of the analyses had 100 outer folds in my nested-cross validation). This gives me a contingency table, with the models as rows and the absolute frequencies for each of the possible hyperparameter categories as columns. For the sake of simplicity, let's call the rows day 1, day 2, and day 3 and let the columns be different ice cream sorts and let the 100 folds be the same sample of people buying ice cream on three different days:

[image: Contigency Table]

As you can 'see', on in order of the days, the distribution becomes less 'spread out'.

I would like to measure this difference in variance, but I am not sure, which test to use. I came upon Chi2, McNemar and Cochrane's Q. Chi2 is not for repeated measures, McNemar only works for 2x2 tables and McNemar & Cochrane's Q are apparently designed for binary responses. Does anybody know which test might be appropriate for my contingency table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally heteroskedastic linear regression: How can I model variance from given predictors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322188/conditionally-heteroskedastic-linear-regression-how-can-i-model-variance-from-g) You are looking for modeling conditional variance, which answers in that thread mention.

Comment: I don't know to be honest, could you give further explanation of how this can solve my problem? Are you sure a linear model is an appropriate model here, as I have two categorical variables (day / model , ice cream sort / hyperparameter)? Of course, 'variance' in my case is a misleading term (I used it intentionally though for illustrating the problem). Of course, you cannot calculate the variance of a categorical variable since there is no mean.